# Chef templates variables " undefined method `bytesize' for #<Hash"

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, httprequest

I'm trying to save the response to an HTTP into a template variable with the following code:

```
    template '/etc/new.conf' do
    owner "root"
    group "root"
    mode "0644"
    source "TestTemp.txt.erb"
    variables(

    my_id: Chef::HTTP.new('https://myIP/').post('/api/sessions/', {'user-
    principal' => '{"userName":"myusername","password":"mypass"}', 'Accept' 
    =>'application/*+xml;version=5.6', 'Content-type' => 'application/json' 
    })  )
    end
```

I'm facing a syntax error in my recipe file:

```
undefined method `bytesize' for #<Hash:0000>` on chef-client convergence on my node.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your `TestTemp.txt.erb` template source?

Comment: Are you facing a syntax error, or a name error?

Comment: I'm facing the following error during my chef-client run: Recipe Compile Error

Comment: my template file is so simple: 
<%= @mystr %>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line break between:

```
'Accept'
```

and

```
=>'application/*+xml;version=5.6'
```

You cannot put a line break between a hash key and the `=>`.

Comment: That would have been a syntax error, not the listed error, you can assume the line wrap is a function of bad copy pasta.

Comment: @coderanger You are right that it is not the listed error. But the OP also mentioned syntax error. The question is not clear.

Comment: The `post()` method expects a string for the body and the user passed in a hash, hence the NoMethodError :)

Comment: the line break is for the copy paste here in the question, not in my code

Comment: if the post method is expecting a string, how could i change the syntax to be string instead of hash

Comment: any help please :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you expect that hash to be the request headers, which would be `.post('/api/sessions/', '', {...})` where that middle bit is the POST body. Also of note, if you are expecting JSON back, you probably want to use `Chef::HTTP::SimpleJSON` instead since that handles the decoding for you.